# Let p be prime and a be an integer such that $p | a^n$ . Is it true that $p^n | a^n$?

Tags: prime-numbers

[image: This is the question I have]

I know that $p|a^n$ is $p|(a)(a)(a)...(a)$, $n$ times and therefore $p|a$. I'm not sure where to go from here - could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the prime factorisation of $a^n$ in terms of the prime factorisation of $a$?

Comment: $p\mid a$ means there is some $k$ such that $pk=a$ ... Can you then guess at an $m$ such that $p^nm=a^n$?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT.** Why not try an example of an integer $a$ and a prime $p$ that might help you see why/why not?

But if you know that $p\mid a$, then $a=pq$ so what about $a^n$? What does that equal given what you just discovered?

Comment: So if a=pq then a^n=(p^n)(q^n) and p^n|a^n because p^n|p^n which is a factor in a^n. Would that be correct?

Comment: Indeed, that is exactly the idea. Then $p^n$ should divide $a^n$ because we know there is an integer $m$ such that $a^n=p^nm$. What is the integer $m$? Well, you just found it: $m=q^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$p | a^n \implies p|a \implies p^n \ | \ a^n$$

This follows from the fact that $p |ab \implies p|a$ or $p|b$

Since, if $p|a$ the result holds. If not $gcd(p,a) = 1$ and from Euclid's Lemma,$ \;p |b$.

By induction we can claim that if $p$ is a prime and $p \ | \ a_1a_2..a_n$ then $p \ | a _i$ for some $i \in \{1, 2, .., n\}$

How?? Well the result is true for $n= 1, 2$ as we have proved above. Suppose the result is true for $n$ that is $p \ | \ a_1a_2..a_n \implies p \ | a _i $. Suppose $ p \ | \ a_1a_2..a_na_{n+1} = (a_1a_2..a_n)a_{n+1} $. Then $p \ | \ a_1a_2..a_n$ or $p \ | a_{n+1} \implies$ result is true for $n + 1$.

Applying this theorem to your problem and using the fact that $a | b$ and $c |d \implies ab |cd$ you can come to a direct solution.